# Send back data from React native app to native app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, react-native

We developing an react native app that will receive data from external native app and send back response data to calling app.

In native app, we sending data to React native app like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ReactNativeApp", "com.ReactNativeApp.ReceiverActivity"));
intent.putExtra("outGoingData", someData);
startActivityForResult(intent, 600);


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 600){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("data");
    }
}
```

We can able to receive data in React native app succesfully , but when trying to send back to native app , we can't

```
Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data", "newData");
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
activity.finish();
```

We always getting resultCode as 0 and intent as null. Both app launchMode configured as 'singleTop' in manifest.xml

Comment: Why are you using this - `getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();`? Aren't you already in that activity?

Comment: @HedeH I can't simply use setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent) where react activity doesn't exist

Comment: So you are getting the data in that activity but return result from somewhere else? Or are you also getting the data the same way you want to return it?

Comment: @HedeH This is my receiver module where i receiving data and send back to calling app

https://gist.github.com/prabakarviji/7b7ba7ceeb8b5356341cf294051617d5

Comment: I see, posted an answer.. hope it helps...

Comment: You found any solution for this?